# How to call method before index and new from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method in my model,

```
def self.interests(user)
    City.joins("INNER JOIN property_of_interests ON property_of_interests.city_id = cities.id").where(:property_of_interests => {:user_id => user})
end
```

I want to call this method into my controller before index and new action, how can I can I do that ?

And all the model and controller are of different entities

If I use before_filter in the controller how will I pass current_user argument to the method ?

Comment: Could you explain better what you want to do, please?

Comment: Perhaps use `before_filter`(http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/22-use-before_filter)

Comment: but I want to pass current_user argument to the method

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar Where and how is `current_user` created? Is it created in another `before_filter`, and is it set up as an instance variable (like `@current_user`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a lambda, in this case `{@interests = Widget.interests current_user}`, into `before_action` to achieve what you want.

**app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb**

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action(only: [:show]) {@interests = Widget.interests current_user}

  def show
    # do something with @interests
  end
end
```

**app/models/widget.rb**

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.interests(user)
    City.joins("INNER JOIN property_of_interests ON property_of_interests.city_id = cities.id").where(:property_of_interests => {:user_id => user})
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to keep interests method inside the model.

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar I figured out a simpler approach and updated my answer.

Comment: In rails 3 there is no call back to ActionMaler::Base, so it gives no method find on before_action

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar My apologies.  I developed my solution on Rails 4.  You can edit my answer and revert it to the old solution if you want.